# Voyager tinymce rich text box add value

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

Hello guys i'm trying to override voyager_tinymce_config.js file to add rich text box youtube add function i enabled in config/voyager.php

```
 'additional_js' => [
        'js/custom.js',
    ],
```

Then i created public/js/costum.js and add voyager_tinymce_config.js code

```
/*--------------------
|
| TinyMCE default config
|
--------------------*/

var getConfig = function(options) {

    var baseTinymceConfig = {
        menubar: false,
        selector: 'textarea.richTextBox',
        skin_url: $('meta[name="assets-path"]').attr('content')+'?path=js/skins/voyager',
        min_height: 6000,
        resize: 'vertical',
        plugins: 'link, image, code, table, textcolor, lists, youtube',
        extended_valid_elements : 'input[id|name|value|type|class|style|required|placeholder|autocomplete|onclick]',
        file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
                if(type =='image'){
                  $('#upload_file').trigger('click');
                }
            },
        toolbar: 'styleselect bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image table youtube giphy | code',
        convert_urls: false,
        image_caption: true,
        image_title: true,
        init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            if (typeof tinymce_init_callback !== "undefined") {
                tinymce_init_callback(editor);
            }
        },
        setup: function (editor) {
            if (typeof tinymce_setup_callback !== "undefined") {
                tinymce_setup_callback(editor);
            }
        }
    };

    return $.extend({}, baseTinymceConfig, options);
}

exports.getConfig = getConfig;
```

I just added in plugins: youtube and in toolbar: youtube giphy

it's don't works nothing added to my rich text box what's i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the function

```
function tinymce_init_callback(editor) {
...
}
```

in your custom.js file to reinitialize tinymce.

Take a look at [Laravel Voyager Tinymce Plugin issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69655186/laravel-voyager-tinymce-plugin-issue)

Also check the available plugins.