# Laravel Voyager Tinymce Plugin issue

Tags: laravel, tinymce, voyager

I am trying to add a plugin to Tinymce in voyager, however I keep getting this
Failed to load plugin: template from url http://domain/admin/plugins/template/plugin.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I've tried to place plugins folder in public or in vendor tcg public folder but nothing work. I've also tried to load plugins from external, still no luck.

Can someone please help Thank you.

```
function tinymce_init_callback(editor) {
    console.log('Init!');
    editor.remove();
    editor = null;

    tinymce.init({
        menubar: false,
        selector: 'textarea.richTextBox',
        skin_url: $('meta[name="assets-path"]').attr('content')+'?path=js/skins/voyager',
        min_height: 600,
        resize: 'vertical',
        plugins: 'link, image, code, table, textcolor, lists, template',
        extended_valid_elements : 'input[id|name|value|type|class|style|required|placeholder|autocomplete|onclick]',
        file_browser_callback: function(field_name, url, type, win) {
                if(type =='image'){
                  $('#upload_file').trigger('click');
                }
            },
        toolbar: 'styleselect bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image table | code',
        convert_urls: false,
        image_caption: true,
        image_title: true,
        // external_plugins: {
        //     'link': '/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.js',
        //     'image': '/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.js',
        //     'code': '/tinymce/plugins/code/plugin.js',
        //     'table': '/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.js',
        //     'textcolor': '/tinymce/plugins/textcolor/plugin.js',
        //     'lists': '/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.js',
        //     'template': '/tinymce/plugins/template/plugin.js',
        // }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I try this also, my solution is:

add to your composer.json

```
"tinymce/tinymce": "4.9.11"
```

because Voyager 1.5 comes with this version of tinymce.

run `composer update` in your terminal to install this version in /vendor

copy the /vendor/tinymce/tinymce directory to /public/js/tinymce

this is my callback function in the custom.js as mentation from the [Voyager documentation](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/additional-css-js)

```
function tinymce_init_callback(editor) {
    editor.remove();
    editor = null;
    tinymce.init({
        menubar: false,
        selector: 'textarea.richTextBox',
        skin_url: $('meta[name="assets-path"]').attr('content') + '?path=js/skins/voyager',
        min_height: 100,
        height: 500,
        resize: 'vertical',
        inline_styles: false,
        keep_styles: false,
        font_formats: 'Open Sans, sans-serif',
        plugins: 'link, image, code, table, textcolor, lists',
        file_browser_callback: function (field_name, url, type, win) {
            if (type == 'image') {
                $('#upload_file').trigger('click');
            }
        },
        toolbar: 'styleselect bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | anchor link image table | print | emoticons | code',
        convert_urls: false,
        image_caption: true,
        image_title: true,
        valid_elements: 'div[*],p[*],span[*],ul[*],li[*],ol[*],hr,br,img[*],i[*],em,table[*],tr[*],td[*],th[*],sup[*],sub[*],strong[*],b,h1[*],h2[*],h3[*],h4[*],h5[*],h6[*],small[*],a[*], svg,path',
        valid_children: '+li[p]',
        external_plugins: {
            'anchor': '/js/tinymce/plugins/anchor/plugin.min.js',
            'print': '/js/tinymce/plugins/print/plugin.min.js',
            'preview': '/js/tinymce/plugins/preview/plugin.min.js',
            'emoticons': '/js/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/plugin.min.js',
        }
  });
```

Note the "/js" in front of the path to the external plugins.
Plugins are loaded and working.

Check /public/js/tinymce/plugins to see the available plugins who come with this version.